# She is poor at writing grammatical English(,) because you can find that she has obvious grammar errors in her English. - difference in meaning?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, appositives, non-restrictive

**Example 1**

> She is poor at writing grammatical English, because you can find that she has obvious grammar errors in her English.

**Example 2**

> She is poor at writing grammatical English because you can find that she has obvious grammar errors in her English.

The comma before "because" means that the info is nonessential.

No comma before "because" means that the info is essential.

However, I am not sure whether the because-clause is essential or not.

How should I distinguish them?

Comment: It flows without the comma. I saw him because I wanted to. Would you put a comma there?

Comment: It is not essential. The fact that there are errors in her English is _evidence_ that she is poor at writing in English, not the _reason_ for it.

Comment: You misunderstand what the comma means here. That stuff about "essential, non-essential" meaings only applies if the relevant clause provides *information about a specific noun phrase* (which usually means a clause starting with ***which, that, who,...***). For example, *My son[,] who is at college phoned me today*, where if the comma ***is not present*** that means it's a "restrictive" clause - containing *essential* information so you know I'm specifically talking about *that* son (not my other son who's *not* at college). With no comma, it just mentions "in passing" that he's at college.

Comment: ...it's also important to remember that commas *only* exist in order to reflect pauses in speech. You should make a point of understanding what my two examples above (with and without the pause reflected by the comma) sound like, because that's the ***real*** English you should be learning. Written English is just a poor attempt to represent the real spoken utterance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You would be better off just writing an answer.  "My son, who is at college, phoned me today. It would take **two commas** not one but the relative clause thing is not even part of the question.

Comment: @Lambie: OP believes that "The comma ... means the info is nonessential", which is *incorrect* here. The reason OP thinks that is because he's misunderstood something he was taught in the context of "essential, non-essential" relative clauses. I wasn't attempting to answer the question. I was just explaining ***why he'd got the wrong idea about commas*** - and I could hardly do that without mentioning relative clauses, could I?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Every time I read the term OP out loud to myself, I think I'm reading a Slav creating a sentence in English. But my basic point is this: don't answer in comments. Write an answer.

Comment: @Lambie: I have no answer to post. If you've got one, by all means post it. The potential comma is irrelevant to me. All I see is a flawed sentence that erroneously conflates "evidence" and "cause", as pointed out by Kate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Whenever I ask you to post an answer rather than give one in comments, you always come up with some reason. So, I guess you are right and I am wrong. But, this is a teaching opportunity and that would be better than throwing out a bunch of language **the** OP might not even get.

Comment: @Lambie: You've been trying to teach me to use the article before OP for years. But I still haven't learnt!

Answer (score 0):

We usually don't use a comma if a subordinate clause follows its main one.  That general practice should apply here.

> She is poor at writing grammatical English because (you can find that) she has obvious grammar errors in her English.

(Sometimes we use a comma before a clause subordinated by **because** when the preceding main clause has a **negation**.  That is not the situation here.  "I’m **not** going to New York because the weather will be cold." will have a different meaning if a comma is added.)

Comment: The OP is correct to use *poor at*, the preposition *in* will normally refer to location or a period of time e.g "The  poor in the 19th century / in Russia during the 1917 revolution". Always check the results of ngrams before leaving an analysis

Comment: ["poor at reading"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22poor+at+reading%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=2cfc6c46286a6e8e&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&prmd=ivn&sxsrf=ACQVn08zM2t9-ixKfmCyGFG-Kvu9rSnK-Q:1707725370816&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXrufgrKWEAxW1RfEDHZ77A5oQpwV6BAgCEBs&biw=360&bih=560&dpr=4)

Comment: Thx, @Mari-Lou A. I have edited my answer.